# Finding and converting navteq coordinates

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, gis

I'm trying to scrape a company's website for coordinates of their retail locations. I need to figure out how to convert the results I'm getting into something usable.

After I submit the search request with the desired area, I get back a page with the locations all plotted on a Navteq map. I'm not having any luck making sense of the coordinate system they're using.

For example, when I look for locations within 100km Stockholm, SE I get something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setActionsMapAfterTimer() {

    clearInterval(timerSetMapAfterDomReady);

    if(!document.getElementById("mapArea"))
        return;

    eplatform.map.init({containerId:"mapArea", onReady: function(map) {

    dealocMap = map;

    var centerBubble = [
        '<div style="padding:0;margin:0;font-size:11px;">',
        '<table>',
        '<tr>',
        '<td style="padding-left:5px;"><b style="font-size: 11px;">stockholm</b></td>',
        '</tr>',
        '</table>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('');

    dealocMap.setCenterLocation(3559.9378979999997, 1083.776436,  100000.0);
    dealocMap.addMarker(3559.9378979999997, 1083.776436,   {bubbleInfos: centerBubble});
```

And for the first location...

```
    var dealerBubble = [
        '<div style="padding:0;margin:0;">',
        '<table>',
        '<tr>',
        '<td><img src="/img/dealers/ICON.gif " /> </td>',
        '<td style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:7px;"><b style="font-size: 11px;">Name</b></td>',
        '</tr>',
        '</table>',
        '</div>',
        '<div style="padding:0;margin:0;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">',
        '<div>',
        '<p style="padding:0;margin:0;">  </p>',
        '<p style="padding:0;margin:0;">Address</p>',
        '<p style="padding:0;margin:0;"></p>',
        '<p style="padding:0;margin:0;">Locality</p>',
        '</div>',
        '<p style="padding:0;margin:0;"><b>Tel.:</b> </p>',
        '<p style="padding:0;margin:0;"><b>Fax:</b> </p>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('');

    dealocMap.addMarker(3549.89404296875 , 1089.7158203125, { bubbleInfos: dealerBubble, icon: "/img/dealers/ICON.gif" });
```

And so on, until the end:

```
        }
        });

    }

    var timerSetMapAfterDomReady;

    window.addEvent('domready', function() {

        timerSetMapAfterDomReady=setInterval("setActionsMapAfterTimer()", 600);

    });

    /**
    * Keep compatibility with dealoc_content.jsp
     */
    function centerOnCoordinate(longitude, latitude, radius) {
        dealocMap.setCenterLocation(latitude, longitude, radius / 2.5);
    }

</script>
```

In this case the map starts out centered at (59.332271,18.062961) and the location listed is (59.1649,18.16193), but I still can't figure out how to convert them. I could just geocode the addresses again, but ones I tried weren't always as accurate as what's on the page.

Any ideas? Thanks!